# What are the advantages and disadvantages of sass-lint

Tags: sass

What are the advantages and disadvantages of sass-lint? While on production compiled minified css goes. How it impact performance?

Comment: Linting does not affect production, it is used during development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sass-lint is a tool used to ensure your SASS files comply to a defined standard before you compile them to css.

By the time your code gets to production the SASS files will have already been compiled down to css & minified css so sass-lint won't have any affect on performance. It may have an affect on build & deployment times, but these would be negligible.